# Why does it take so long for my water to run hot and why does it not last in the shower?

Tags: plumbing, water, water-heater, faucet

I have a State electric compact water heater model 6-120.  When I run the faucet it seems to take a long time for the water to run hot. About a minute or two.  When I take a shower I can run the hot water for about twenty minutes and then it goes cold.

Is this normal? I live in a three bedroom, two story townhouse. But I'm the only one living here. The shower is on the second floor.  The water heater is on the first floor. But even the tap closes to the water heater takes too long to warm up. Do I have a problem? A plumber installed it for me in 2012.

Also, do I need to do anything to maintain the water heater or to improve performance. Like flush it or something?

Comment: FYI, there is no model 6-120.  That is a family of water heaters.  Your model is something like *PCE 6 1OMSA*.  Also, have you actually *timed* how long it takes to get hot water?  When you're waiting for something, it may seem much longer than it actually is.

Comment: I'm assuming it's a tank heater, but what size tank is it (40 gallon, 50 gallon, etc. )? If it's a 40 gallon, 20 minutes sounds about right. Though one of the elements could be dead or dieing.

Comment: What is the flow rate of your shower head? Simple example but if you have a 20 gallon tank and a 1 gallon a minute shower head then you will run out in 20 minutes.

Comment: 20 minutes? And I thought I took long showers! :)\

Comment: You can adjust the temperature setting of the thermostats that control the heating elements on your water heater. It is a simple screw adjustment. Sometimes people turn them down to save energy/money but it doesn't pay to flush 30 gallons of water down the drain. Turn it up for more hot water.

Comment: That was a great suggestion Jimmy Fix-It. I adjusted the temperature and it has improved somewhat. You're right about wasting all that water waiting for it to heat up.  Now the temperature is set to just below scalding at about 155 degrees. It really seems too high, according to the manual but the water now seems to run hot quicker. Thanks for the suggestion. The water heater was bought new for me by my plumber in 2012. I didn't pick it. It's the compact model. I don't know how many gallons. Maybe it's too small?

Comment: I just looked at State's web site. I think it's the lowboy model. Capacity either 38 or 47 gallons. I can't see the model number on the water heater.